# Testing CSS ':hover' pseudo-class

Tags: javascript, css, hover, casperjs

I'm having real trouble testing the behaviour of my CSS :hover pseudoclass. 
I've tried the following approach, as well as wrapping the `test.assertEquals` in an event listener as `casper.on('mouse.move', function(){test.assertEquals(...);})` to no avail. I've also tried multiple combinations of `casper.mouse.move` and `casper.mouseEvent('mouseover', rightArrowId);` with no result either.

The relevant part of my tests is the following. I'm just testing a webpage running on localhost and all my other tests run just fine.

```
...
var rightArrowId = "#right";
casper.test.begin("On hover, navigation widgets change their opacity", function(test) {


casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture("aboutToMove.png");
    casper.mouse.move(rightArrowId);
    test.assertEquals(customAsserts.isOpaque(rightArrowId), true, "On hover, the 'right' widget becomes opaque");
});


casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture("afterMove.png");
});

casper.run(function() {
    test.done();
});
...
```

```
var customAsserts = {
    isOpaque: function(selector) {
        return casper.evaluate(function(selector) {
            return (document.querySelector(selector).style.opacity === "1");
        }, selector);
    }
};
```

In addition, the screenshots show that the mouse is actually moving, since I can see the hover effect in the second picture but not in the first one.

The relevant CSS, which gets loaded when the page is loaded, is this:

```
#right {
    opacity: 0.35;
}

#right:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.style` only accesses the style that is defined throught the `style` attribute on the element. What you want is to use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
isOpaque: function(selector) {
    return casper.evaluate(function(selector) {
        return getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(selector)).opacity === "1";
    }, selector);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. For some reason, I forgot that pseudo-classes' effects also get reflected in `getcomputedStyle`. Thanks a lot!